# Unknown error: '<class 'KeyError'>' (“The cache has no package named wine1.6-i386”)

Tags: wine

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. The error:

```
Unknown error: '<class 'KeyError'>' (“The cache has no package named wine1.6-i386”)
```

keeps showing in the panel on the desktop. I installed wine some time ago to use only one specific program, but it never worked and I don't really need wine. So I just uninstalled the program as well as wine and hoped this would solve the problem, but it didn't.

I found other posts with a similar problem here, but those solve the problem by updating wine and I wanted to delete it from the system.

What does the error mean? Are there any processes that try to access wine or is it independent of the wine installation? What can I do about it?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Unknown error: '<class 'KeyError'>' ("The cache has no package named wine-staging-i386")](https://askubuntu.com/questions/581480/unknown-error-class-keyerror-the-cache-has-no-package-named-wine-stagin?rq=1).

For me this did the trick:

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error. This fixed problem for me:

`sudo apt install --reinstall wine1.6-i386`

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but this is the same problem as with the answer above: I want to get rid of wine and rid of the error message. Isn't there a way to do this?

Comment: @LNA As above, duh...

Answer (score 0):

For Ubuntu 16.04 LTS or later, you can simply run

```
sudo apt-get install wine1.6
```

Comment: But this means, that I have to install wine1.6 which I don't need just to get rid of the error message???

Comment: @LNA Yes, then you uninstall it. Only a properly installed package can be properly uninstalled.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to uninstall just run:

```
sudo apt remove wine
```

If you also want to remove any related packages run:

```
sudo apt purge wine
```