# ' Unknown Error: '<class 'KeyError'>' ("the cache has no package named 'linux-headers-5.19.0-41-generic:amd64'")'

Tags: cache, linux-headers

I am relatively new to Ubuntu, and have just installed version 20.04 onto a 120GB solid state drive. I have just gotten this error and noticed that neither my WiFi nor my Ethernet are working, I have searched for other similar errors on Google, and tried to use the terminal to install the package. However, due to the WiFi and Ethernet not working, I was unable to. I was wondering if anyone has had this issue before and would be willing to help me.

The error I have is as follows:

```
An error occurred, please run Package Manager from the right-click menu or apt-get in a terminal to see what is wrong.
The error message was: ' Unknown Error: '<class 'KeyError'>' ("the cache has no package named 'linux-headers-5.19.0-41-generic:amd64'")'.
This usually means that your installed packages have unmet dependencies
```

Comment: Sounds like a bad install. Did you verify the ISO the Live Media was made with? Did you follow the tutorial? https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/how-to-verify-ubuntu#1-overview  https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop#1-overview

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unknown error: '<class 'KeyError'>' ("The cache has no package named wine-staging-i386")](https://askubuntu.com/questions/581480/unknown-error-class-keyerror-the-cache-has-no-package-named-wine-stagin)

Comment: Just required a fresh install, something must have been corrupted when installing from the USB stick, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I am getting the same error after installing Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS yesterday, although I am having no obvious consequences; my network connection works.  This is obviously an inherent problem with Ubuntu since I made no changes and the problem occurred immediately.  I am also getting [the same error regarding firefox:amd64,](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1477415/unknown-error-class-keyerror-the-cache-has-no-package-named-firefoxam) but with no noticeable consequences.  It's possible this is a result of my choosing the Minimal installation, and/or choosing to download updates during installation.

Since we have the same error, there is probably nothing wrong with the ISO's integrity.  There is something wrong with Ubuntu on the developers' end, not ours.

Sorry this isn't much of an answer; I don't have enough reputation to make a comment.

In full, Ubuntu tells me "An error occurred, please run Package Manager from the right-click menu or apt-get in a terminal to see what is wrong.  The error message was: ' Unknown Error: '<class 'KeyError'>' ("the cache has no package named 'linux-headers-5.19.0-50-generic:amd64'")'.  This usually means that your installed packages have unmet dependencies".

There is no Package Manager in the right-click menu and I don't know how to make apt-get tell me what is wrong.  Does anyone know?

Edit: running the Software Updater seems to have fixed it, but I don't know why this happened in the first place since I told Ubuntu to download updates during installation.