# Unknown Error:' <class 'KeyError'> '("The cache has no Package named "firefox:amd64')

Tags: firefox, virtualization

today morning when i log in my vm(ubuntu 22.04),i found myself Can't connect to the Internet，and it gives me an error notification:

```
Unknown Error:' <class 'KeyError'> '("The cache has no Package named "firefox:amd64')
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I get this everytime I start my pc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try `sudo apt-get install --reinstall firefox`.

Comment: thanks a lot,it helps me solve the problem! but i wonder why this happened? i didn't do anything

Comment: The firefox package may be corrupted.

Answer (score 0):

I am getting the same error after installing Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS yesterday, as my only OS, not in a VM, although I am nevertheless able to use Firefox.  This is obviously an inherent problem with Ubuntu since I made no changes and the problem occurred immediately.  I am also getting [the same error regarding linux-headers-5.19.0-50-generic:amd64,](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1465604/unknown-error-class-keyerror-the-cache-has-no-package-named-linux-he) but with no noticeable consequences.  It's possible this is a result of my choosing the Minimal installation, and/or choosing to download updates during installation.

So you've done nothing wrong.  There is something wrong with Ubuntu.

Sorry this isn't much of an answer; I don't have enough reputation to make a comment.

In full, Ubuntu tells me "An error occurred, please run Package Manager from the right-click menu or apt-get in a terminal to see what is wrong.  The error message was: ' Unknown Error: '<class 'KeyError'>' ("The cache has no package named 'firefox:amd64'")'.  This usually means that your installed packages have unmet dependencies".

There is no Package Manager in the right-click menu and I don't know how to make apt-get tell me what is wrong.  Does anyone know?

Edit: running the Software Updater seems to have fixed it, but I don't know why this happened in the first place since I told Ubuntu to download updates during installation.

Comment: yeah, so in the end i choose to install the manjaro dual system instead